# Converting a ruby structure to a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, web, savon

I've got a bit of a headache here - I'm pretty new to Ruby...

I've got a structure like so returned from Savon...

```
{
  :item => [{
              :key =>  "result",
              :value=> "success"
            },
            {
              :key =>  "data",
              :value=> {
                  :item => [{ :key => "displayName", 
                              :value => "Matt" 
                            },
                            {
                              :key => "messages",
                              :value => { 
                                  :items => [{....}]
                            }
                       ]
               }
       }]
}
```

And I need to get it to be like...

```
{
  :result => success
  :data => [{
              :displayName => "Matt"
           },
           {
              :messages => [{
                              :messageName => "Test Message"
                           }]
           }]
}
```

So I can easily manipulate and navigate the data structure
I've tried a few methods including just passing the value of :item ...

```ruby
def convertData(data)
  result = {}
  if(data!=nil)
    data.each do |item|
      key = item[:key] 
      value = item[:value] 
      if(value.instance_of?(Hash))
        result[key] = convertData(value[:item])
      else
        result[key] = value
      end  
    end
  end
  return result
end
```

But this just gives me a tonne of Type errors for symbol to integer conversion (I assume that's the array index playing up). Any help much appreciated.

Comment: what do you have in items?

Comment: Usually symbol-to-integer is a sign you're trying to use an Array like you would a Hash. Also note that Ruby strongly encourages people to use method names like `convert_data`.

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov I have literally the first structure stored in a variable that I'm passing to convertData

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the advice! Literally brand new to this as of this morning :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to tackle problem like this in Ruby, it's useful to think of it in terms of *transformations* on your data. The Ruby [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html) library is full of methods that help you manipulate regular data structures like Array and Hash.

A Ruby solution to this problem looks like:

```
def desavon(data)
  case (data)
  when Hash
    if (data[:item])
      data[:item].collect do |item|
        { item[:key] => desavon(item[:value]) }
      end
    else
      # raise error?
    end
  else
    data
  end
end
```

Here's some sample input data and sample output:

```
input = {
  item: [
    {
      key: "result",
      value: "success"
    },
    {
      key:  "data",
      value: {
        item: [
          {
            key: "displayName", 
            value: "Matt" 
          },
          {
            key: "messages",
            value: { 
              item: [
                {
                  key: 'messageName',
                  value: 'Test Message'
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

desavon(input)
# => [{"result"=>"success"}, {"data"=>[{"displayName"=>"Matt"}, {"messages"=>[{"messageName"=>"Test Message"}]}]}]
```

I think this version looks better, output-wise, but that's a call you'll have to make:

```
def desavon(data)
  case (data)
  when Hash
    if (data[:item])
      Hash[
        data[:item].collect do |item|
          [ item[:key], desavon(item[:value]) ]
        end
      ]
    else
      # raise error?
    end
  else
    data
  end
end

desavon(input)
# => {"result"=>"success", "data"=>{"displayName"=>"Matt", "messages"=>{"messageName"=>"Test Message"}}}
```

Note that the `case` statement here is really the key, it allows you to quickly differentiate between different types of data you're converting, and the `Hash[]` method converts key-value pairs into the Hash structure you're looking for.

This is similar to your attempt, but just passes through content it doesn't recognize as-is.

Comment: That's perfect thank you - I'm learning already I need to approach Ruby with a different method of thought than I'm used to! Enjoying the challenge though.

Answer (score 1):

Savon provides a `to_hash` method on the result.
What I usually do is:

...

```
response = @client.request :wsdl, :conversion_rate do
  soap.body = {
    "FromCurrency" => from_curr,
    "ToCurrency" => to_curr
  }
end    
response.to_hash[:conversion_rate_response][:conversion_rate_result];
```

...
full script here https://gist.github.com/sroller/3d04842ab763f52b6623

Comment: Thank you, the problem seemed to revolve more around the structure - I blame this WSDL i'm having to use. I'll keep this in mind though next time I'm using a SOAP API :)